# Kafka-Node: How to consume messages synchronously after commit previous one

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka

Kafka consumer gets bombarded with lots of messages at a time,
I need to receive them one after another only after committing the first one.
I tried `autoCommit:false`, and tried to use `pause()` and `resume()` too on receiving the data. But still, it doesn't work.
Is there a way to achieve this in this library?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `max.poll.records` property of the consumer to restrict the number of messages, which are returned by calling `poll()` method.